# Downloading Office file causes aspx page reload three times before opening the file

Tags: asp.net, ms-office, download

I have a web application allowing to download files from the server. Documents might be Office files (.docx, pptx, .xslx) or Pdf.

The logic is quite simple: on click from client side a web service is called and calls an aspx page (Print.aspx) passing the needed parameters. Print page calls a web service to retrieve the selected documents binaries and write them in the response:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName = Request.QueryString["fname"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(documentID) == false)
        {
            byte[] document = GetPhysicalFile(documentID); //Get the binaries
            showDownloadedDoc(document, fileName);
        }
    }

private void showDownloadedDoc(byte[] document, string fileName)
{
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = contentType;

Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\"", fileName));
Response.BufferOutput = false;
Response.BinaryWrite(document);
Response.Close();

 }
```

Pdf documents are opened in the Print.aspx page and the aspx page is loaded only once. For Office files, the Page_Load() method is invoked 3 times.

After the first time the dialog for Open/Save the document is opened and if "Open" ic clicked, then the Page_Load is called twice and after that the document is finally oepend in MS Word, for instance.

Is there a way I can prevent to have multiple page loads for opening these documents? I would like to avoid having to save the file on Server Side and Redirect to that URL, since a file for each access would be created.

Comment: is there a reason why you are not using a `GenericHandler` for this? ashx

Comment: I thought using my approach would have been the easiest way to achieve the need of letting users download documents (application is used in the company's intranet only). How a GenericHandler would solve my current issue with multiple page load?

Comment: With genericHandler I would not have the same LifeCicle as for an aspx page (+1, good idea).

Comment: to just create a download, you probably don't need the asp Page LifeCycle, do you? The LifeCycle is for the generation of WebForms. The above example code has no relation to WebForms and could possibly be a lot faster with a GenericHandler. Besides you won't have the Page_Load event any more and so it cannot be called multiple times. It seemed like an easy fix to me, but apparently you don't use the GenericHandler for a good reason.

Comment: I've added an example with a GenericHandler.

Comment: Thanks for the code. Unfortunately i discovered I cannot use a GenericHandler in my case. My aspx web application is developed as "plugin" on top of a legacy software. This software overwrites the standard session/context making it not possible to use handlers. If I try to access the ashx file the context passed is null and an exception is thrown. Therefore I have to return back to my orignal aspx page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example with a GenericHandler

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{

  string filePath; // get from somewhere
  string contentType; // get from somewhere

  FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);

  context.Response.Clear();
  context.Response.ContentType = contentType;
  context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFilename(filePath));
  context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileInfo.Length.ToString());
  context.Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
}
```

Comment: I will wait before accepting the answer in order to see whether a solution for my case is found. In any case another +1 for the good hint and code.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you make post back with click and then you avoid to let the response replay back to notifies the ViewState that the command was complete and update the content on the page.

So on the next click the old command is still waiting and resend it by page, and now you have two commands - two calls, but then again you do not let the return to update the viewstate again and the page thinks that must wait again.

And this continues on every next call, the code behind is actually try to run all the previous one.

The solution to this is to have a direct link to the handler and not call it from code behind with ajax.

Comment: Actually the page is loaded 3 times at each single button click (even at the first click after IIS reset and code deploy). However I am implementing a GenericHandler.ashx instead of the aspx page to see whether this helps.

Comment: @luca if you have place the code I may have a better image for help.

Comment: I added in the question the code I use to send the binaries to the client once retrieved.

Comment: @Luca You see, you do what exactly/almost I have say. You can not do that, you must find a diferent way. The post back must be continue and ends up with a replay. Direct use a handler and a link to what you like to download.

Comment: +1 - As written above to Bazzz I cannot use a GenericHandler unfortunately.